# Is a mobile game's world-wide visibility in app stores affected by the publisher's country of residence?

Tags: android, ios, country

I've noticed on Apple Store (and I assume on Google Playstore too) I find different games and apps in France than in the US. Does this mean if my company resides in a small country and I register my game in this country, it'll only be shown to users of my country? Or is it just a matter of some settings and I can decide to be shown all around the world, for instance for American users (which is a larger market than my country), same as game producers living there?

Does a game developer's country of residence influence how many downloads world-wide he can reach at all?

My question is about Apple Store and Google Playstore, but answers for other platforms are welcome too.

Comment: You have to select countries where you want your app to be shown while uploading apk on playstore

Comment: And why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvoted but this question is not related to programming

Comment: How to publish your app/game is essential for game developers and thus it's related to programming in my view

Comment: I’m voting to close my own question because it's not programming related and it's not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a matter of settings. You can select some countries or worldwide when you fill a form to publish your app.

Ads are selected with the user's current location. Admob, Facebook and Amazon handle this for you.